# Prove that every half-plane is a nonempty set.

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I have no idea how to prove this. If you had just a line that made the half-planes and nothing else then why couldn't it be empty? Can anyone give me an idea on how to prove this or maybe explain it?

Comment: What's your definition of a half plane?

Comment: My definition of half-plane is a subset of plane P that isn't on line l.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an axiom which say that in the plane you have a point that is not on the line. So, if that point lies in that half plane you want it to lie, you will prove that that part is nonempty. Otherwise, you consider the line that pass through that point A and some point B on the line. You will get a line through these points A and B. By axiom there exist a point C such that A-B-C, in that order. The point C must lie in your half plane. The proof is finished :)